# Repeat each values of an array different times

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose `a = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6]` and `s = [3, 3, 9, 3, 6, 3]`. I'm looking for the best way to repeat `a[i]` exactly `s[i]` times and then have a flatten array in the form of `b = [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, ... ]`.

I want to do this as fast as possible since I have to do it many times. I'm using Python and numpy and the arrays are defined as numpy.ndarray. I searched around and find out about `repeat`, `tile` and `column_stack` which can be used nicely to repeat each element `n` times but I wanted to repeat each of them different times.

One way to do this is:

```
a = hsplit(a, 6)
for i in range(len(a)):
    a[i] = repeat(a[i], s[i])
a = a.flatten()
```

I am wondering if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: is your repeat function `np.repeat?`

Comment: @Kasra Yes, it is. I didn't know that it also accepts list for repeat.

Comment: so you must wrote `np.repeat` !!! please be careful about  your questions validation and clear !!!

Comment: You are right, I tested it a lot but I missed this. Sorry.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

That's exactly what [`numpy.repeat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) does:

```
>>> a = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6])
>>> s = np.array([3, 3, 9, 3, 6, 3])
>>> np.repeat(a, s)
array([ 0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.2,  0.2,  0.2,  0.3,  0.3,  0.3,  0.3,  0.3,
        0.3,  0.3,  0.3,  0.3,  0.4,  0.4,  0.4,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5,
        0.5,  0.5,  0.6,  0.6,  0.6])
```

In pure Python you can do something like:

```
>>> from itertools import repeat, chain, imap
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(imap(repeat, a, s)))
[0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6]
```

But of course it is going to be way slower than its NumPy equivalent:

```
>>> s = [3, 3, 9, 3, 6, 3]*1000
>>> a = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6]*1000
>>> %timeit list(chain.from_iterable(imap(repeat, a, s)))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.21 ms per loop
>>> %timeit np.repeat(a_a, s_a) #a_a and s_a are NumPy arrays of same size as a and b
10000 loops, best of 3: 202 µs per loop
```

Comment: by far the most efficient

Comment: Cannot believe I didn't test this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner using only (nested) list comprehensions:

```
[item for z in [[x]*y for (x,y) in zip(a, s)] for item in z]
```