# Using np.repeat on sub-arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I'm working on a little 2d rejection-sampling function, and I'm running into a problem with `np.repeat()`. I want to be able to feed my function, `rejection_sample_2d()`, an array of `x` values, an array of `y` values, and a 2D probability distribution array with dimensions corresponding to the size of `x` and `y`. So far, I've managed the following:

```
def rejection_sample_2d(x, y, z, nper = 100):
    '''
    sample `nper` times from each bin of 2D PDF `z`
    '''

    import numpy as np
    import numpy.random as r

    #normalize
    z /= z.sum()
    mc = r.random(z.shape + (nper,))
    selected = mc < z[:,:,np.newaxis]
    number = selected.sum(axis = -1)
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    coords = np.dstack((xx, yy))

    return np.repeat(coords, number[:,:,np.newaxis])
```

`coords` is a 3d array, but it can be thought of as a 2d grid of coordinates, and I want to build another array that has, for example, `number[0,0]` instances of `coords[0,0]`.

For instance, let's say that

```
coords = [ [ [0., 0.], [1., 0.], [2., 0.] ],
           [ [0., 1.], [1., 1.], [2., 1.] ],
           [ [0., 2.], [1., 2.], [2., 2.] ] ]
number = [ [    1    ,    1    ,    2     ],
           [    3    ,    2    ,    3     ],
           [    4    ,    4    ,    5     ] ]
```

in this case, the result will be `[ [0., 0.], [1., 0.], [2., 0.], [2., 0.], ... ]`

I saw a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26038778/repeat-each-values-of-an-array-different-times), but when I tried to scale it up to higher dimensions, it didn't work. The above function throws the following error at the last line:

```
ERROR: ValueError: object too deep for desired array 
[numpy.core.fromnumeric]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/users/zpace/python-personal/plotting_tools.py", line 233, in rejection_sample_2d
    print np.repeat(coords, number[:,:,np.newaxis])
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 390, in repeat
    return repeat(repeats, axis)
ValueError: object too deep for desired array
```

Is there (a) a better/more dimensionally-general way to approach this, or (b) a fast way to use `repeat()` to solve this? I can resort to list comprehensions, but I'd rather not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
>>> np.repeat(coords.reshape(-1, 2), number.ravel(), axis=0)
array([[ 0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.],
       [ 2.,  0.],
       [ 2.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  2.],
       [ 0.,  2.],
       [ 0.,  2.],
       [ 0.,  2.],
       [ 1.,  2.],
       [ 1.,  2.],
       [ 1.,  2.],
       [ 1.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  2.]])
```

Comment: Cool, thanks! In the meantime, I found a workaround (below), but I'm using your solution instead.

Answer (score 0):

I like @Ashwini's answer below, but for the sake of completeness, here's a workaround...

You can select from `xx` and `yy` individually, and stack the two arrays together:

```
np.column_stack(( np.repeat(xx.flatten(), number.flatten()), np.repeat(xx.flatten(), number.flatten()) ))
```

This is a little less intuitive, but it does the job (Ashwini's is totally better, though)